# How can I sort within partitions defined by one column but leave the partitions where they are?

Tags: python, sorting, pandas, numpy

Consider the dataframe `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        A=list('XXYYXXYY'),
        B=range(8, 0, -1)
    ))

print(df)

   A  B
0  X  8
1  X  7
2  Y  6
3  Y  5
4  X  4
5  X  3
6  Y  2
7  Y  1
```

With the `'X'` group defined by column `'A'`, I want to sort `[8, 7, 4, 3]` to the expected `[3, 4, 7, 8]`.  However, I want to leave those rows where they are.

```
   A  B
5  X  3  <-- Notice all X are in same positions
4  X  4  <-- However, `[3, 4, 7, 8]` have shifted
7  Y  1
6  Y  2
1  X  7  <-- 
0  X  8  <-- 
3  Y  5
2  Y  6
```

Comment: I am really sorry for this. In this answer I add comment if want add more general solution (with dot and `.eq(1)`), but it seems you dont think it is necessary. (I am wrong? Or not?) So for this reason I add it to my answer. But I think you get me know it is problem for you, then I remove this part of answer. Please always get me know if this problem in future, especially if thin border between my and your solution. So sorry.

Comment: I am a lot thinking about it and my main problem was I dont know it is problem for you. But I have small kindness. Can you help me how answer in link in comment change? I need some sample how write sentence like `credit belongs to another user:` (or is necessary something different (my english is not so nice, unfortunately)). thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `transform` to get back your new desired index order, then use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to reorder your DataFrame:

```
# Use transform to return the new ordered index values.
new_idx = df.groupby('A')['B'].transform(lambda grp: grp.sort_values().index)

# Reindex.
df = df.reindex(new_idx.rename(None))
```

You could combine the two lines above into one long line, if so desired.

The resulting output:

```
   A  B
5  X  3
4  X  4
7  Y  1
6  Y  2
1  X  7
0  X  8
3  Y  5
2  Y  6
```

Note that if you don't care about maintaing your old index, you can directly reassign from the `transform`:

```
df['B'] = df.groupby('A')['B'].transform(lambda grp: grp.sort_values())
```

Which yields:

```
   A  B
0  X  3
1  X  4
2  Y  1
3  Y  2
4  X  7
5  X  8
6  Y  5
7  Y  6
```

Comment: I didn't expect that to work!  I anticipated that the index would auto realign.  `transform` doesn't do that!  Very good to know.  Now I'll have to test it :-)

Comment: I also didn't expect it to perform as well as it does on larger data sets.  I've got some more thinking to do on how to do this with numpy.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I figured how to solve this efficiently was to sort twice and unwind once.

```
v = df.values

# argsort just first column with kind='mergesort' to preserve subgroup order
a1 = v[:, 0].argsort(kind='mergesort')

# Fill in an un-sort array to unwind the `a1` argsort
a_ = np.empty_like(a1)
a_[a1] = np.arange(len(a1))

# argsort by both columns... not exactly what I want, yet.
a2 = np.lexsort(v.T[::-1])

# Sort with `a2` then unwind the first layer with `a_`
pd.DataFrame(v[a2][a_], df.index[a2][a_], df.columns)

   A  B
5  X  3
4  X  4
7  Y  1
6  Y  2
1  X  7
0  X  8
3  Y  5
2  Y  6
```

---

***Testing***

**Code**

```
def np_intra_sort(df):
    v = df.values
    a1 = v[:, 0].argsort(kind='mergesort')
    a_ = np.empty_like(a1)
    a_[a1] = np.arange(len(a1))
    a2 = np.lexsort(v.T[::-1])
    return pd.DataFrame(v[a2][a_], df.index[a2][a_], df.columns)

def pd_intra_sort(df):

    def sub_sort(x):
        return x.sort_values().index

    idx = df.groupby('A').B.transform(sub_sort).values

    return df.reindex(idx)
```

*Small data*

[image]

*Large data*

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        A=list('XXYYXXYY') * 10000,
        B=range(8 * 10000, 0, -1)
    ))
```

[image]