# Pandas dataframe order

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],
                   'B':[3,2,1,1,3,2,3,2,1]})
```

[image: iamge2]

I want to rearrange column B so that it appears as:

[image: image3]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and specify columns:

```
df = df.sort_values(['A','B'])

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],
                   'B':[3,2,1,1,3,2,3,2,1]})

df = df.sort_values(['A','B'])
#alternatively
#df.sort_values(['A','B'], inplace=True)
print (df)
   A  B
2  1  1
1  1  2
0  1  3
3  2  1
5  2  2
4  2  3
8  3  1
7  3  2
6  3  3
```

---

```
df = df.sort_values(['A','B']).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
   A  B
0  1  1
1  1  2
2  1  3
3  2  1
4  2  2
5  2  3
6  3  1
7  3  2
8  3  3
```

Comment: Small advice - [Don't post images of code (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Got it.  Thanks.  That worked.

Comment: @jezrael, do you have a fall-back for versions of `pandas` prior to 0.17.0?

Comment: My `pandas`, version `0.15.2`, doesn't have the `sort_values()` method. The [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) claims that it is "New in version 0.17.0", which is evidently incorrect.

Comment: I do have an alternative solution but it's pretty ugly...

Comment: was previously called .sort()

Answer (score 1):

This leaves `'A'` alone, and sorts within the groups.
Notice that indices are left as is.

```
df.assign(B=df.groupby('A').transform(lambda x: x.sort_values()))

   A  B
0  1  1
1  1  2
2  1  3
3  2  1
4  2  2
5  2  3
6  3  1
7  3  2
8  3  3
```

Please see [**This Question**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43196550/2336654) and the associated answers.  Credit goes to ***@root***  If this answer is helpful to people, please follow the link and upvote root's answer there.  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks.  This also works.

Comment: @magicsword please do me a favor and follow link and upvote root's answer there.  thx.

Comment: @magics this (like my answer) handles the indexes differently from the answer you accepted. Which one matches your requirements?

Comment: I accepted jazrael's answer because I did not care about the indexes.  I am using column A as a reference.

Answer (score 0):

I have pandas version `0.15.2`, which does not have the `DataFrame.sort_values()` method. So here's a fall-back that sorts and replaces the two columns:

```
df.loc[:,["A", "B"]] = sorted(zip(df.A, df.B))
```

Comment: Hmm, and how works `df = df.sort(columns=['A','B'])` ?

Comment: In `0.17.0` it was rename - [check](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#changes-to-sorting-api).

Comment: That preserves row labels, i.e. it scrambles the index: It becomes `[2, 1, 0, 3, 5, ...]`

Comment: Maybe some bug, is impossible upgrade? Last version is 0.19.2 and soon 0.20.0

Comment: Time to update your pandas alexis...:)

Comment: @jezrael I see your solution also scrambles the index! I assumed the OP wanted the index preserved, but maybe the question is just bad.

Comment: Yes, index is always scrabbled, if need nice index need add `.reset_index(drop=True)`

Comment: I.e. look at the OP's indexes; your answer doesn't match the desired result _as stated._

Comment: Ok, I edit answer.